# Button in Angular form being "clicked" when I press enter

Tags: html, angular, forms, angular-reactive-forms

I'm have a strange issue in my Angular form. I have a simple form like the following:

```
<form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f)" novalidate>
      <button (click)="addUser()">Add a user</button>

      <input name="first" ngModel required #first="ngModel">
      <input name="last" ngModel>

      <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

The problem is that when I press `ENTER` when in the form, instead of submitting, it fires the function `addUser()`, which is not what I want it to do.

How do I stop it from "clicking" `ADD A USER` and firing `addUser()`?

Answer (score 5):

The solution was simply to add the type attribute with value `button` to the first button.

The browser assigns `type="submit"` by default to all buttons.

Simply needed to change

`<button (click)="addUser()">Add a user</button>`

to

`<button (click)="addUser()" type="button">Add a user</button>`